# Why use $HOME over ~ (tilde) in a shell script?

Tags: shell, scripting, environment-variables, home-directory, tilde-expansion

Is there any reason to use the variable `$HOME` instead of a simple `~` (tilde) in a shell script?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Tilde expansion doesn't work in some situations, like in the middle of strings like `/foo/bar:~/baz`

Comment: For another example of where it does not work, scroll to the answer by @no_allotment .

Answer (score 17):

Portability and uniformity of `$HOME`. Tilde is a typing shortcut.

Comment: So I'm correct in understanding that there are shells or systems in which tilde is not synonymous with $HOME?

Comment: @Michael yes, the default `sh` in Solaris 10 does not treat tilde as `$HOME` neither is does expand `~username`.

Answer (score 15):

Today I found tilde expansion doesn't work in double quotation(`""`).

In zsh(sorry I didn't check the behavior of other shells.),

> Inside double quotes (`""`), parameter and command substitution occur

Tilde expansion is a **filename expansion**, so it fails inside double quotation.
`$HOME` is a **parameter substitution** and can be expanded inside double quotation.
`$HOME` is a safe bet.