# Print a cowsay in a new terminal

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, spawn

I want to run a script called tuxsay that combines fortune and cowsay to have tux say some words of wisdom. I made an alias in by .bash_aliases calling it tuxsay and executing the script

```
FORTUNE= $(fortune)
cowsay -f tux $FORTUNE
```

I then have a script that will spawn a new terminal and I want it to output the results of my first script then allow me to work in the terminal, something like

`xterm -e "tuxsay&"`

So how can I spawn a new terminal use cowsay then allow me to work in it?

Specifics: I have a startup script that will spawn applications that I typically use, and I want it to spawn a terminal that runs my tuxsay script then allows me to work. I am on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and am running dwm 6.0

Comment: What happens when you try what you have? I don't see a reason to use a `&`, also, as I assume `tuxsay` will just print your message and return.

Comment: `xterm -e <command> <othercommand>` doesn't spawn anything, but if it only has one command it spawns a new xterm.

Comment: Spaces are not allowed on either side of the equals sign in variable assignments: `FORTUNE=$(fortune)`.

Comment: Fixed, still cant spawn the terminal though

Answer (score 2):

Why not just add your command to your `.bashrc` file?  Then it will be run every time a new interactive shell is started.  You can test if the `$TERM` variable contains "xterm", and make your output conditional upon that.  e.g.  add the following line to the end of `.bashrc`:

```
[[ "$TERM" =~ xterm ]] && tuxsay
```

**Update**

While I think the above is still probably the most useful general answer, I noticed a few more things:

- `tuxsay` is a bash alias.  bash aliases are only understood within bash itself, but when you pass a command to `xterm -e`, that command is executed directly by the xterm without any bash involvement.  The system won't be able to find and execute a file called "tuxsay" and will fail.
- If executed from bash, the `&` character will put tuxsay command (alias) in the background, but this doesn't really help here.  What you need is a new shell to start up once tuxsay is done.
- Be careful with `.bash_aliases`.  I noticed on my Redhat-based system that aliases placed in this file were not working, because `.bash_aliases` file is not sourced in.  ([My Bash aliases don't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548093/my-bash-aliases-dont-work))  So it looks like `.bash_aliases` is sourced by default from Ubuntu-based systems, but no guarantees for others.

With the above in mind, if you definitely want tuxsay to run on a per-xterm basis – i.e. you want to specify this on the xterm command line – you could do the following one-liner:

```
xterm -e 'cowsay -f tux $(fortune); bash'
```

This passes the *compound* command `cowsay -f tux $(fortune); bash` to xterm.  This compound command consists of two commands: first do the `cowsay` thing, then start bash.

You could also put these two commands in a shell script and pass the shell-script to xterm.