# Trouble setting variable in a bash script

Tags: bash

I am having trouble with a very simple bash script (test.sh):

```
if [ $# >=1 ]
then
  backup_file=$1
else
  backup_file=~/standard.tar.bz2
fi

echo $backup_file
```

If I pass an argument:

```
test.sh myfile
```

I get the expected output: `myfile`

Otherwise, I get no output. I am expecting to see (when test.sh is executed with no arguments): `~/standard.tar.bz2`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Feel free to take advantage of the resources listed on the [tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info), such as [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) which automatically diagnoses things like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This condition evaluation is the problem:

```
[ $# >=1 ]
```

Change this to:

```
[ $# -ge 1 ]
```

OR else in BASH:

```
[[ $# -ge 1 ]]
```

OR:

```
(( $# ))
```

- `[...]` and `[[...]]` don't allow `>=` as an operator
- You need a space after operators.

Comment: or `(( $# ))`, or `[ -n "$1" ]`. The last is slightly different, but may be more valuable in some context.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using mathematical operators, use it in the correct context.  Instead of saying:

```
if [ $# >=1 ]
```

say

```
if (( $# >=1 ))
```

(And you don't have to worry about spaces around the operators, or lack thereof.)

Answer (score 3):

Others have addressed the immediate syntactical problem, but a completely different way to write this would be to take advantage of [parameter expansion to use a default value](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#use_a_default_value):

```
backup_file="${1:-$HOME/standard.tar.bz2}"
```

This will replace backup_file with the value in `$1` if and only if it exists.

Comment: You can still use `~` instead of `$HOME` for the default value.

Comment: @chepner right, but I actually prefer HOME in scripts, because ~ does some other expansions that are probably not desirable (even if they're unlikely to happen by accident). To each his own. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930671/why-use-home-over-tilde-in-a-shell-script)